# Decode bytes in NSData into integers

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsdata

I have a 16 Bit Two's Complement characteristic from a BLE device. Its contains 9 integers at byte numbers: 0-1, 2-3, 4-5 .... to 16-17.

Data type is `NSData` and looks like this:

```
<faff0100 1b00ab00 daff9141 5603c0fd 06f2>
```

How do I extract the integers?

Comment: This has nothing to do with UTF-16, which is used to encode text. Your rather want to specify what language you plan to use.

Comment: Hi, probably my lack of knowledge re UTF-16.

I'm using Objective_C

Answer (score 1):

Your data is basically a 9 element array of integers.

If you work with Objective C, you can access via the `bytes` method. I want to check is has the correct length first:

```
int16_t numberArray[9];
NSData* data = ...; // your NSData instance
memcpy(numberArray, [data bytes], 18);

NSLog(@"First number: %d", numberArray[0]);  // bytes 0-1
NSLog(@"Second number: %d", numberArray[1]); // bytes 2-3
NSLog(@"Third number: %d", numberArray[2]); // bytes 4-5
...
NSLog(@"Ninth number: %d", numberArray[8]); // bytes 16-17
```

Comment: It's also worth to mention the 'length' method. (Amount of bytes that the NSData object represents) => https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSData/length

Comment: Hi, great...but. Works brilliant for the first number. But how do I access the value at byte 12-13?

Comment: @Codo What makes you sure that the start of the byte array is properly aligned so that its content can be reinterpreted as integers? I guess it actual is -- but it's worth mentioning that this approach is potentially dangerous which might cause a crash.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Yes, indeed. To be on the safe side, it's better to copy the bytes first into a properly aligned array. The simulator (i386) won't have a problem with the alignment, but the ARM CPU does.